# Get logged user id from firebase using python

Tags: python, firebase

To fetch the generated unique logged user id (like `04bb0de6-167e-45e7-8580-c9b4adcdc87f`) token from firebase, we will use `.getAuth().getUid()` in java. What is similar command to it in python to get the logged user id

Comment: Which library are you using in Java, which in Python?

Comment: in java we are using `com.firebase.client`, in pyhon its 'firebase'

Comment: Do you mean https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-firebase/1.2?

Comment: yes, its `https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-firebase/1.2`

Answer (score 2):

The [Python Firebase library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-firebase/1.2) that you're using communicates with the [Firebase REST API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/). This REST API does not have functionality to create or authenticate users with Firebase's email+password or OAuth providers. From the [documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/user-auth.html):

> The Firebase JavaScript, Java, and Objective-C libraries provide built-in functionality for many login providers, but the REST API works a little differently. The REST API's goal is to be flexible and platform independent. Custom Login aligns with this goal by allowing you to generate user login tokens with your own server side code.

The only option available when accessing the REST API for specific users is to (and the one the library uses) is to mint a custom auth token for the user. That is indeed what the Python Firebase library does, as shown in this code snippet from [their site](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-firebase/1.2):

```
authentication = firebase.Authentication('THIS_IS_MY_SECRET', 'ozgurvt@gmail.com', 
                                         extra={'id': 123})
firebase.authentication = authentication
print authentication.extra
```

> {'admin': False, 'debug': False, 'email': 'ozgurvt@gmail.com', 'id': 123, 'provider': 'password'}

So the id of the user is whatever you pass in to the `extra` parameter.